# Historical updates mysql node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

Hi I am using node JS with MYSQL and trying to see how historical updates work with node-mysql. I am facing a problem in which when I try to update a row with `ID`  in my table, I would like to get that row, update it with a new time stamp and then insert a new row with ID 2 but no update time stamp.

Example

```
ID | Owner | app | status | INSERT_DT           | UPDATE_DT 
 1     11     Ok     1       2015-15-20 13:00:21 NULL
```

Now when I update the above row by changing the status, it should be come

```
ID | Owner | app | status | INSERT_DT           | UPDATE_DT 
 1     11     Ok     1       2015-15-20 13:00:21 20-15-20 12:00:12
 2     11     Ok     0       2015-15-20 12:00:12 | NULL
```

So I get the row like this..

```
getUserPath = (Owner) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query('SELECT * from path where Owner = ?', Owner, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            reject('Could not get user path');
        }
        resolve(results[0]);
    });
});
```

The update below is where I am not sure how to update the whole row.
So the `data` includes all the information above

```
UpdateUserPath = (data) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
data.INSERT_DT = '2015-15-20 12:00:12';
    db.query('UPDATE path set data', data , function(err,results,fields){
        if(err){
            reject('Could not update user path');
        }else{
            if(results.affectedRows > 0){
                //Making the new row
                data.ID = null;
                insertNewPath(data);
            }else{
                reject('Could not update user path');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The update statement returns me an error, and I am not sure how to get it working.
I am assuming the set needs me to manually let which fields to update, but I would not like to do that, I want it to happen all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you update statement is wrong. if you trying to update table above it should be:

```
db.query('UPDATE path set ID=?, Owner=?, app=?, status=?, INSERT_DT=?, UPDATE_DT=?',[data.ID,data.Owner,data.app,data.status,data.insert_dt,data.update_dt] , function(err,results,fields){ ...
```

Comment: But there is nothing called as data while setting it, I dont think mysql understands what I am trying to set.

Comment: I actually know the above statement, I just thought if there was a easier way of doing it.